# docker registry ping 404

Tags: docker, ping, docker-registry

I have created a docker registry with

```
docker run
-e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=s3
-e STORAGE_PATH=/registry
-e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy
-p 5000:5000 
registry
```

and by ping become

```
172.17.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2017:17:56:47 +0000] "GET /v2/_ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" ""
```

But I can push and pull images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/994

> The ping endpoint for the registry is /v2/ not /v2/_ping

Comment: It works. But I use registry-ui https://github.com/atc-/docker-registry-ui and can not change it.

Comment: Sorry, I am stupid:( Do you mean I can change it? How?

Comment: No, the software has an issue with the ping URL that needs to be fixed. I posted the issue.